# Problem with derivatives and shape

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f,g$ be continuously differentiable functions 69 times on [0-$\infty$]. Without using Taylor theorems for a) and b):

a) Prove that if $g$ is such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 63}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-63)^{50}}=0$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 63}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-63)^{n}}=0$ for n from $0$ to $50$.

b) Find values of $p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3$ and guess the value of $p_{50}$ if $g$ satisfies a) limit and is a polynomial of the form $g(x)=p_0+p_1(x-63)+p_2(x-63)^2+\cdots+p_{50}(x-63)^{50}$

c)Using b), can you know something about $f$ shape around $x=63$?

My attempt:

a)You only need to do induction, right? Using no hypothesis. You multiply by $(x-63)$, which also goes to 0...

b) I think $p_0=g(63)=f(63)$, but no idea about the others

c) No idea either.
Any hints?

Comment: a) You don't need induction, just multiply by $(x-63)^{50-n}$ for $n<50$ and use given limit for $n=50$.

Comment: b) Using a), you can write $p_i$ as limits:$\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-63)^0}=0 \Rightarrow$ $\lim_{x\to 63} (f(x)-p_0)=0 \Rightarrow$ $p_0=\lim_{x\to 63} f(x)=f(63)$. $\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-63)^1}=0 \Rightarrow$ $\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-p_0-p_1(x-63)}{x-63}=0 \Rightarrow$ $\lim_{x\to 63} p_1 = \frac{f(x)-p_0}{x-63}$ and so on.

Comment: Also $p_i$ can be expressed in terms of derivatives of $f(x)$ in $x\to 63$, then you can find general formula for $p_i$ and guess $p_{50}$.

Comment: I dont understand how to expand that to $p_2$ and so on. And part c)?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-63)^2}=$
$\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-p_0-p_1(x-63)-p_2(x-63)^2-p_3(x-63)^3-...}{(x-63)^2}=$
$\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-p_0-p_1(x-63)}{(x-63)^2}-p_2=0 \Rightarrow$
$p_2=\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-p_0-p_1(x-63)}{(x-63)^2}$. And so on.
$p_{50}=\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-p_0-p_1(x-63)-p_2(x-63)^2-...-p_{49}(x-63)^{49}}{(x-63)^{50}}$

Comment: I don't know what terms are supposed for description of shape in part c). As we know $f(x)$ is 69 times continously differentiable, so part b) gives not much new information about shape of $f$, except that this shape is close to that of $g$ in vicinity of $x=63$. But the size of this vicinity depends on value of first successive derivative of $f$ at $x\to 63$ which  is not equal to that of $g$, it may be $f^{(51)}(63)$ or higher.

Comment: But how can we express $p_2$ as f derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is combining my comments with small addition.

At $0\leq n \leq 50$: $$\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-63)^n}=\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-63)^{50}} \lim_{x\to 63} (x-63)^{50-n} = 0 \cdot (0 {\rm \ or\ } 1)=0$$

At $g(x)=p_0+p_1 (x-63)+...+p_{50} (x-63)^{50}$:

$$\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-63)^n}=\\ \lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-p_0-p_1(x-63)-...-p_{n-1}(x-63)^{n-1}-p_n(x-63)^n-p_{n+1}(x-63)^{n+1}-...}{(x-63)^n}=\\ \lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-p_0-p_1(x-63)-...-p_{n-1}(x-63)^{n-1}}{(x-63)^n}-p_n=0 \Rightarrow \\ p_n=\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f(x)-p_0-p_1(x-63)-...-p_{n-1}(x-63)^{n-1}}{(x-63)^n}$$

Let use L'Hospital's rule and take $n$ derivatives of both numerator and denominator (if we take less derivatives denominator stays tending zero at $x\to 63$):

$$p_n=\lim_{x\to 63} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n(n-1)(n-2)...1\cdot(x-63)^0}=\frac{f^{(n)}(63)}{n!}$$

I don't know what terms are supposed for description of shape in part c). As we know $f(x)$ is 69 times continously differentiable, so parts a) and b) give not much new information about shape of $f$, except that this shape is close to that of $g$ in vicinity of $x=63$. But the size of this vicinity depends on value of first successive derivative of $f$ at $x\to 63$ which is not equal to that of $g$, it may be $f^{(51)}(63)$ or higher.